# Animations with requireJS and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Anybody know if the angularJS animations work with requireJS? ng-animate isn't recognized when I use requireJS modules. If anyone know how to get it working can you explain what the best approach is? I should add that I am indeed using the angularJS version 1.1.4

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is MVW framework and requireJS is AMD loader. So the problem is in your module complatibility or setup or something else and not in requireJS.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of this. I worked on it some more part of it was my setup but still having issue. I am looking at possibly the need to inject the $animator service or something. not quite sure yet

Answer (score 0):

I just grabbed this from one of my abandoned angular apps - but seems to work just firing it up now.

Hope it helps. Oh I should mention this is javascript based animation using jquery (fadeIn and fadeout).

```
var myApp = angular.module('apps', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.animation('animate-enter', function () {

   return {
    setup: function (element) {           
        var viewId = element.parent().attr('id');
        $("#" + viewId).hide();
    },
    start: function (element) {
        var viewId = element.parent().attr('id');

        $("#" + viewId).fadeIn(500, function () {
        });
    }
}
```

});